# Thymeleaf : How to edit a field?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

In my class Test I have a list of Versions like this :

Test Class:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "idTest")
    private List<Versions> version;
```

In thymeleaf I code this to display the list of version

```
 <tr th:each ="test : ${testList}">  
   <td th:each="p : ${test.version}" th:text="${p.getVersions().version}" > </td>
</tr>
```

This work for me.

Now **I would edit it** (Version field), my code :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${update}" th:action="@{/update}" method="post">

<div class="col-sm-10">
    <th:block th:each="p : ${version}" >
       <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{p.getVersions().version}"/>
    </th:block>
</div> 
</form>
```

It display only the label Version, and it doesn't show the version input 
Have you any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: try this:  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${p}"/>, 
Where "p" is just a single version from a list of versions

Comment: @Afridi it doesn't work, I get this error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'p' available as request attribute

Comment: Sorry this one:  <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{p}"/>
I mean replace "$" with *

Comment: I tried it also , it says : Invalid property 'p' of bean class

Answer (score 0):

It seeems you're not iterating the object correctly. Try this:

```
<tr th:each ="test : ${testList}">  
  <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${update}" th:action="@{/update}" method="post">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <th:block th:each="p : ${test.version}" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{p.getVersions().version}"/>
      </th:block>
    </div> 
  </form>
</tr>
```